# how to get max depth for one node in xpath 1.0

Tags: php, xpath

I need to retrieve the max depth for one node in the easiest way (PHP 5, XPATH 1.0)

**Example of XML :**

```
<node>
    <node id="nodeBase">
        <node>
            <node />
        </node>
        <node>
            <node>
                <node />
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>
</node>
```

1. I get the node **nodeBase**
2. Execution of an XPATH Query to get the max depth from **nodeBase**
3. The result must be 3

Is there possible to do that without coding a complicate algorithm in PHP ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.I get the node nodeBase
>
> 2.Execution of an XPATH Query to get the max depth from nodeBase
>
> 3.The result must be 3   Is there possible to do that without coding a complicate algorithm in PHP ?

**Unlike using XPath 2.0, the wanted result isn't possible to produce with single XPath expression in XPath 1.0**.

The simplest solution will involve some computations from the host language (in this case PHP).

1. You can get all leaf elements that are descendants of the specified element.
2. For each of them evaluate `count(ancestor::*)` then in PHP find the maximum of these.
3. Finally, subtract from the so found maximum absolute depth the depth of the specified element, which is again `count(ancestor::*)`  evaluated off this element.

**The XPath expression (needed in 1. above) that selects all leaf elements is**:

```
//node[@id='nodeBase']//*[not(*)]
```

**XSLT 1.0 implementation of this algorithm**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="vBase" select="//*[@id='nodeBase']"/>
     
     <xsl:for-each select="$vBase//*">
      <xsl:sort select="count(ancestor::*)" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
      
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
       <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::*) - count($vBase/ancestor::*)"/>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<node>
    <node id="nodeBase">
        <node>
            <node />
        </node>
        <node>
            <node>
                <node />
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>
</node>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
3
```

From this you could get an idea how to implement the algorithm in PHP.

**Just for completeness, here is a single XPath 2.0 expression producing the same result**:

```
 max((//*[@id='nodeBase'])[1]//*[not(*)]/count(ancestor::*))
-
 (//*[@id='nodeBase'])[1]/count(ancestor::*)
```

Comment: @Epharion: We need to show the vendors of programming languages that a large majority of developers need XPath 2.0 (and XSLT 2.0). At present XPath 3.0 is just about to become an official W3C Recommendation (it is in "last call" status) -- this means that PL vendors are very late in the game -- they still haven't implemented 2.0.